# Passing Data Through UITableViews In Multiple Segues in Xcode (Three Segues)

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, segue, identifier

The setup I have is three View Controllers, the first two with a UITableView and the third with an image.

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3sNY.png)

I would like to pass data from a firstViewController to a secondViewController and then both sets of data to a thirdViewController via segues using UITableViews.

The code I am using to pass from firstViewController to the secondViewController is as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier1", sender: candy[indexPath.row])
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let selectedCandy = segue.destination as? SecondViewController
    selectedCandy?.showCandy = sender as? String
}
```

Very similar for the code in secondViewController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier2", sender: flavors[indexPath.row])
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let selectedFlavor = segue.destination as? ThirdViewController
    selectedFlavor?.showFlavor = sender as? String
}
```

The gist of what I am doing is to select a Candy in the firstViewController UITableView, select a Flavor in the secondViewController UITableView, and then have a label FLAVOR CANDY and an image of the selection in the thirdViewController.

The label for the Flavor does show.  The label for the Candy does not.  How can I pass the selection from the segue for the Candy to the thirdViewController?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You should pass candy to the last controller, in `prepareFor:sender:` in the second VC. The controller should have `showCandy` instance variable, from the first VC. Pass that along to the third VC. Also, your variable names are not optimal, confusing as hell.

Comment: `showCandy` really sounds like a method, or a `Bool`, it really should be `selectedCandy`. In the `prepareFor:sender:`, you named your local variables of destination view controllers as `selectedXXX`, when they really should take the type name (camelCased, like `secondViewController`) or at least end them with `Controller`. `selectedCandy` sounds like the object that was selected.

Comment: Thanks Shane!  Quick follow-up:

I amended the code in the secondViewController to this:

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let selectedFlavor = segue.destination as? ThirdViewController
        selectedFlavor?.showFlavor = sender as? String
        
        let selectedCandy = segue.destination as? ThirdViewController
        selectedCandy?.showCandy = sender as? String
        
    }

However, now it shows the Flavor twice instead of Flavor-Candy.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Very much appreciated for your help!

Answer (score 0):

FirstViewController

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier1", sender: self.candy[indexPath.section])
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "identifier1" {
            let goNext = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
            goNext.showCandy = sender as! String
        }
    }
```

SecondViewController

```
var showCandy = ""

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier2", sender: self.flavors[indexPath.section])
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "identifier2" {
            let goNext = segue.destination as! ThirdViewController
            goNext.showCandy = showCandy
            goNext.showFlavor = sender as! String
        }
    }
```

ThirdViewController

```
var showCandy = ""
var showFlavor = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(showCandy)
        print(showFlavor)
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @iParesh.  This fully answers my question.  You rock!